# Akka Remote multiple connections

Tags: akka, akka-remote-actor

I hava two servers A and B. They communicate via Akka Remote. Actors in server B watch actors in server A.
When server A restarts to upgrade, there may be two tcp connections initiated by B to A. 
Now if server B sends message to Server A. The akka log for server B shows the sending of request but not receiving of response. The Akka log for server A shows the receiving of request and sending of response.
I'm using Akka 2.3.12
So what happens? What I should to to avoid it?
Thanks

Comment: Same as discussed on the Akka mailing list? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/akka-user/connections/akka-user/GYkFfR_ISUI/LCuMDW0wDgAJ